# Using webpack on a common Symfony Bundle

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I have a "common" bundle that is used on several Symfony projects. This bundle contains the assets we use on our different projects (js and css).
Until now this bundle was mainly adding assets with macros that allowed to load the libraries cdn.

```
{% macro daterangepicker_js() %}
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
{% endmacro %}
```

We use macros to load only the scripts we want for each page. We manage the dependencies ourselves.

But we want to start using npm + webpack to manage the js library updates (jquery, bootstrap,etc...). So I installed webpack on the "common" bundle (and not on our different projects). I also created an entry for each library (see code below). And to avoid re-importing all dependencies in each entry, I activated the splitEntryChunks option.

Now my webpack.config.js look like this:

```
Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('Resources/public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    .setManifestKeyPrefix('bundles/commonbundle')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('jquery', './assets/jquery.js')
    .addEntry('jquery-datepicker', './assets/jquery-datepicker.js')
    .addEntry('bootstrap', './assets/bootstrap.js')
    .addEntry('bootstrap-select', './assets/bootstrap-select.js')


    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()

    .enableSourceMaps(false)
    .enableVersioning(false)
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .configureSplitChunks(function (splitChunks) {
        // change the configuration
        splitChunks.name = true;
        splitChunks.chunks = 'all';
    })
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })
```

And my twig macros look like this :

```
{% macro jquery_js() %}
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/runtime.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/vendors~bootstrap~bootstrap-select~jquery~jquery-datepicker.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/jquery.js') }}"></script>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro bootstrap_js() %}
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/runtime.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/vendors~bootstrap~bootstrap-select~jquery~jquery-datepicker.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/vendors~bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro bootstrapselect_js() %}
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/runtime.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/vendors~bootstrap~bootstrap-select~jquery~jquery-datepicker.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/vendors~bootstrap-select.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/bootstrap-select.js') }}"></script>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro datepicker_js() %}
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/runtime.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/vendors~bootstrap~bootstrap-select~jquery~jquery-datepicker.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/vendors~jquery-datepicker.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/jquery-datepicker.js') }}"></script>
{% endmacro %}
```

I can't use {{ encore_entry_script_tags() }} because webpack is not installed on our mains applications so y tried to load the chunks myself.

It's really ugly and it doesn't even work.

Bootstrap-select initialization is called 4 times and I end up with duplicate selection fields.

also, I have this error message from datepicker :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'regional' of undefined

How can i improve the webpack configuration ?
If possible, I would like to continue to use exactly the same macros, i can't refactor all our other project to stop using them.

Comment: Why not load all common files exactly once?

Comment: @NicoHaase Where should I load them? I don't know which ones are necessary.
Sometimes I only want to load datepicker, I don't need the bootstrap-select dependencies.

Comment: Why not implement a service that helps to keep track of this?

Comment: @NicoHaase It seems to me to be over-complexification. I was hoping that webpack would allow me to do this natively.

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to accomplish with webpack? It looks like you're attempting to use webpack as you would assetic, which are very different methodologies. You may want to use Grunt instead of webpack for what your doing in your templates and the inability to use `encore_entry_script_tags()`. I also don't understand why you can't use `encore_entry_script_tags` on your rmains, since webpack should produce production based code as js that you would just push from dev, without the need to use nodejs/webpack on the production server.

Comment: @WillB. I will try to see if Grunt better suits my needs.
Maybe there's something I didn't understand but I don't have the webpack-encore package installed on my main application. So when I put the twig encore_entry_script_tags function in the macro defined in the common bundle, my main application crashe.

Comment: @WillB. My main goal is to be able to manage the update of js libraries with a simple command like "npm install" or something like that.
Webpack mainly allows me to import node modules simply.

Comment: Yes, you would need to install and enable the [`symfony/webpack-encore-bundle`](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore-bundle) in your `prod` environment, As for compiling the assets, doing so is expected to be done from your dev environment with the `encore production` flag and pushed. So `nodejs` is not required to be installed on the production environment at all. However, the way you are going about using webpack in your templates, removes the benefits of using webpack to manage your application assets, since Webpack would effectively replace your macros.

Comment: You can configure `grunt` to do what you're looking for as well as `concat` and `terser` the scripts as desired like that of what webpack performs.

Comment: @WillB. I know but i'm stuck with this macros because I can't update all the applications that use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to change my chunks configuration and now it's easier to maintain inside my macros
webpack.config.js :

```
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .configureSplitChunks(function (splitChunks) {
        splitChunks.name = function (module, chunks, cacheGroupKey) {
            const moduleFileName = module.identifier().split(/[\/,\\]/).reduceRight(item => item).replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
            return `${cacheGroupKey}~${moduleFileName}`;
        };
        splitChunks.chunks = 'all';
    })
```

it creates one chunk per library, but then it's easy to divide them into my macros.

```
{% macro jquery_js() %}
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/runtime.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/vendors~jquery.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/jquery.js') }}"></script>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro bootstrap_js() %}
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/vendors~jquery.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/vendors~bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro bootstrapselect_js() %}
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/vendors~jquery.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/vendors~bootstrap-select.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/commonbundle/build/bootstrap-select.js') }}"></script>
{% endmacro %}
```

The vendors/chunks are duplicated but the browser don't load them each time because they are the same file, so it's ok.

It's probably not the cleanest solution but it works in my specific use case.